# How to compute the number of steps in binary search?

Tags: python, data-structures

This code returns only the position of the target.
I need to compute number of steps also.
How can I modify this code to achieve my goal?

```
def binary_search(arr, low, high, x):
    if high >= low:
        mid = (high + low) // 2
        if arr[mid] == x:
            return mid

        elif arr[mid] > x:
            return binary_search(arr, low, mid - 1, x)

        else:
            return binary_search(arr, mid + 1, high, x)

    else:
        return -1
    
LT = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
pos = binary_search(LT,0,9,5)
print(str(pos))
```

Comment: you could have an incremented global variable or pass a counter to each recursive call

Comment: You'll want to fix the indentation. Other than that, do you just need the value somewhere, or do you need the function to return the whole result (both answer and depth)?

Comment: A side note: don't make the caller pass in the initial high and low. You can calculate these from the list and provide defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add it as a *function parameter* and update *recursively*

```py
def binary_search(arr, low, high, x, steps = 0):

    if high >= low:
        mid = (high + low) // 2
        if arr[mid] == x:
            print(f"found at {steps} steps")
            return mid
    
        elif arr[mid] > x:
            return binary_search(arr, low, mid - 1, x, steps + 1)
    
        else:
            return binary_search(arr, mid + 1, high, x, steps + 1)
    
    else:
        return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary search code in Python without recursion :

```py
def binary_search_itr(arr, size, val,step=0):    
    ln=0
    r = size-1
    mid = (ln + r) // 2
    
    while (arr[mid] != val and ln <= r):        
        if val < arr[mid]:
            step = step + 1
            r = mid - 1
        else:
            step = step + 1
            ln = mid + 1
        mid = (ln + r) // 2
        
    
    if arr[mid] == val:
        step = step + 1
        return mid,step    
    return -1

LT = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
pos = binary_search_itr(LT,9,9)
print(pos)
```

Comment: please add a description of your problem or question